# Describe the two parts of a 'T' shaped intersection

Tags: word-choice

I have architectural drawings that contains numerous instances of intersecting walls that form a **'T' shape.** To state the obvious, a capital 'T' has two parts:

1. the top line
2. a vertical line that buts up against the T's top

What might each of these two connected walls or segments be called?

I am asking for word suggestions. The words may or may not be math-based.  Short words (short number of characters) that most people understand are preferred over obscure words that few people understand.

**Edit:**
I'm currently using 'T-Top' for one. That's okay I guess, but I couldn't think of anything short for the vertical piece.

Comment: In typography, [it seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_anatomy) the vertical line is a *stem* and the horizontal line is an *arm*. Probably not good terms in your case, though.

Comment: How can intersecting walls form a T shape? There are T-beams and T-shape columns. T beams have a flange (top of the beam) and the vertical part is a web or stem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-beam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like your 'T-Top' you could use 'T-Shaft' or 'T-Leg'.

*Shaft* or *column* and *capital* or *cap* or *lintel* would describe the joint in terms of the **T** and keep it in the architectural domain—but it might create confusion with vertical elements.

If the wall which constitutes the horizontal of the *T* is the primary load-bearer, you might write of a *main* and an *intersecting* or *butted* or *abutting* wall—or a *mainwall* and a *buttwall*.

If the wall which constitutes the vertical of the **T** is primary, you might write of a *main(wall)* and a *crosswall* or *crossing wall*.

Or it might be best to consult an architect for appropriate terms of art.

Comment: +1 I think the *main* or *continuous* wall and the *abutting* or *intersecting* wall are very good choices.

Comment: Not sure this is right, really. There are T-beams and T-shape columns.